# Giving newbies time to think

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer, late-answers

Maybe it’s just me, however, there are some questions where there exist much better answers somewhere which are not the accepted one. I understand that for an answer to be accepted, it just need to "work for the proponent of the question".

Nonetheless, a recurrent pattern seems to happen. Many of those answers seem to be chosen as accepted by new users (it happened to me for example). It is also common to see questions with a single answer accepted in less than 24 hours following the same pattern.

I understand that coming from outside, never using this site; it may be tempting to accept the first person who was “nice enough” to answer us or just because of confirmation bias.

So, my question is: **Why not giving new users at least 24 hours before they can accept any answer**, considering that this is the time frame that most answers occur?

Comment: On some other SE sites, it is custom to leave a comment on new users' questions who have accepted an answer so quickly, saying much what you say here, but I think there's little hope currently of this being implemented as a system feature that actually technically prevents users from accepting answers so quickly, if that's what you're asking for.

Comment: @ACuriousMind. Yep. That was my question. Something similar to what happen when we start a bounty and try to award the prize in less than 48 hours. In this case, you receive a reminder notifying you that you must wait for a certain time to able to do that.

Comment: This meta question seems to belong to the [mother meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) as Phys.SE cannot make such changes to the SE engine.

Comment: @Qmechanic. I think you’re right. Actually I’ve been thinking on this 30 seconds after posting the question. Unfortunately I don’t know How to move it to the main SE-meta page.

Comment: Well, the SE team does monitor "child metas" for feature requests. So I don't think this necessarily _needs_ to be sent to the mother meta. But if you really do want it sent there, you can either delete it here and repost it there, or a moderator can migrate it for you.

Comment: I have answers that have been upvoted in less time than it takes to read the entire post.  This bad habit is kinda annoying actually. So nevermind newbies: many users should take a long and deep breath before voting.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Reading speed can differ quite a lot from one person to another, and some can read _really_ fast (I usually read quite fast).

Comment: @ZeroTheHero regarding fast upvotes, I feel another explanation is that half the answer (or the general principles) may already be known to the user, but reading an answer may provide the missing link, or it's purely an instinctive response to learning something new. I feel that you deserve an explanation if you meant your answer to: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/370645 which I think  I  u/v, pretty much hot off the press. (Although maybe you don't mean that question). Anyway, we can each sleep more soundly now,  hopefully.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Sometimes, I will read an answer and the first few words/paragraph is exactly what I was thinking a good answer would look like.  Sometimes I vote it up while I keep reading.  If for some reason the answer breaks down halfway and turns to crap, I retract my vote before it goes through.  If an answer looks incredibly long I usually don't though; because then there's a chance I can't retract the vote by the time I'm done.  It's not a great habit; but I've found myself forgetting to upvote good posts otherwise.

Comment: Waiting 24 hours can also mean that the new user posts a question, reads the first answer, notices that he can't accept the answer and disappears without leaving trace, forgetting about the whole thing. It happens already, it would get worse.

Comment: I think a lot of new users create an account in order to ask a single specific question and then never return once it's been answered. If there were a mandatory 24-hour delay before an answer could be accepted, then I think a lot of new users would receive the correct answer very quickly and then never bother to log back in and accept it 24 hours later. So I suspect that if implemented, this change would increase the number of correctly answered questions whose answers aren't accepted (bad) more than it would increase the number of questions whose best answer is accepted (good).

Comment: Even if they don’t log back to accept an answer, I think it will remain better for the community to have the “best” answer (in terms of votes at the top), rather than having quit poor answers in that position.

Comment: I thing users do come back in the first 24 hours. The thing is (if nobody noticed before ;-), the number of answers grow fast, causing an expectation of what is next for new users.

Comment: @tparker I would bet the users you allude to are highly likely to do no diligence.  I agree that, for these impatient white rabbits, 24hrs would likely bring about the “abandon without upvote” syndrome.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero:  I have sometimes upvoted answers in less time than it takes to read them, and I am fairly sure I've done this to at least one of **your** answers.   The reason for this is that I started to post an answer of my own and then quickly realized that you (or someone else) had already posted exactly what I was going to say.   It does not always take a careful reading to determine this.  In that case, I  generally upvote instead of posting a duplicate answer.

Comment: @WillO I’m thankful for your confidence but unfortunately I submit you should always read my answers in full, if only to point out the not-so-occasional gobbledygook that I can produce.

Comment: I'm in favour of there being no such thing as "accepting an answer" on physics.se.  The OP doesn't know the correct answer, or they wouldn't be asking the question.  They're in no better position than anyone else to judge the quality of an answer - and most likely in a worse position.  So why give them anything weightier than the standard upvotes and downvotes?  This isn't Stack Overflow; and the concept of "this answer worked for me" just doesn't make sense for physics.se.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Insightful! Never thought about it this way. In StackOverflow one can test the answer and check whether it worked for him or not. This is not the case in Physics.SE most of the times.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem - "This answer works for me" often translates to "Now I understand."

Comment: Well, except that if the answer is wrong, and OP thinks it's right, then they _don't_ understand.  I've seen wrong answers accepted on this site from time to time, and I don't see why the respondent should be rewarded for being able to bluff the OP.  At least on a site like Stack Overflow, OP can test the answer and discover whether it works (although often they don't).

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem - I think this is **really** a good point, and it deserves an independent question itself here in Meta.